# Try/Except in Python: How to avoid duplication?

Tags: python, python-decorators, contextmanager

I have a class that converts low-level exceptions raised by an API into high-level ones. The class is filled with complex, duplicated error handling logic. I'm looking for the pythonic way of reducing this duplication.

Here's a contrived example.

```
class ApiWrapperException(Exception):
  pass

class ApiWrapper(object):

  def __init__(self, api):
    self._api = api

  def do_one_thing(self):
    print 'do_one_thing stuff before API call'
    try:
      self._api.do_one_thing()
    except ApiException:
      print 'ApiWrapper caught an ApiException. Doing complicated error handling logic. Raising a different exception.'
      raise ApiWrapperException
    print 'do_one_thing stuff after API call'

  def do_another_thing(self):
    print 'do_another_thing stuff before API call'
    try:
      self._api.do_another_thing()
    except ApiException:
      print 'ApiWrapper caught an ApiException. Doing complicated error handling logic. Raising a different exception.'
      raise ApiWrapperException
    print 'do_another_thing stuff after API call'
```

In this example, the `ApiWrapper` class converts the low-level `ApiException` into the nicer `ApiWrapperException`. But there's a lot of duplication.

### Option 1: Use a function wrapper

I can put the duplicated code in an inner function, like this:

```
def handle_api_errors(api_callable):
  def call(*args, **kwargs):
    try:
      return api_callable(*args, **kwargs)
    except ApiException:
      print 'ApiWrapper caught an ApiException. Doing complicated error handling logic. Raising a different exception.'
      raise ApiWrapperException
  return call
```

The `ApiWrapper` class simplifies to:

```
class ApiWrapper(object):

  def __init__(self, api):
    self._api = api

  def do_one_thing(self):
    print 'do_one_thing stuff before API call'
    handle_api_errors(self._api.do_one_thing)()
    print 'do_one_thing stuff after API call'

  def do_another_thing(self):
    print 'do_another_thing stuff before API call'
    handle_api_errors(self._api.do_another_thing)()
    print 'do_another_thing stuff after API call'
```

### Option 2: Use a context manager

I can put the duplicated code in a context manager, like this:

```
@contextlib.contextmanager
def handle_api_errors():
  try:
    yield
  except ApiException:
    print 'ApiWrapper caught an ApiException. Doing complicated error handling logic. Raising a different exception.'
    raise ApiWrapperException
```

The `ApiWrapper` class simplifies to:

```
class ApiWrapper(object):

  def __init__(self, api):
    self._api = api

  def do_one_thing(self):
    print 'do_one_thing stuff before API call'
    with handle_api_errors():
      self._api.do_one_thing()
    print 'do_one_thing stuff after API call'

  def do_another_thing(self):
    print 'do_another_thing stuff before API call'
    with handle_api_errors():
      self._api.do_another_thing()
    print 'do_another_thing stuff after API call'
```

### Option 3: use a decorator (as suggested by @ZachGates)

I can put the duplicated code in a decorator, like this:

```
def handle_api_errors(api_calling_func):
  def decorated_func(*args, **kwargs):
    try:
      api_calling_func(*args, **kwargs)
    except ApiException:
      print 'ApiWrapper caught an ApiException. Doing complicated error handling logic. Raising a different exception.'
      raise ApiWrapperException
  return decorated_func
```

The `ApiWrapper` class simplifies to:

```
class ApiWrapper(object):

  def __init__(self, api):
    self._api = api

  @handle_api_errors
  def do_one_thing(self):
    print 'do_one_thing stuff before API call'
    self._api.do_one_thing()
    print 'do_one_thing stuff after API call'

  @handle_api_errors
  def do_another_thing(self):
    print 'do_another_thing stuff before API call'
    self._api.do_another_thing()
    print 'do_another_thing stuff after API call'
```

Which option would be considered most pythonic? Are there better options?

Comment: Personally, I would use a decorator to wrap whichever functions are the exception handlers. In my mind, the intent behind a decorator is clearer than wrapping each call, but that's by no means based on fact.

Comment: I agree with @ZachGates, why don't you just use a decorator?

Comment: @ZachGates Good point. A decorator is definitely an option. The code flow would not be strictly the same as in the baseline code, since the "stuff" parts before and after the API call will get included in the try/except handler. But that's not an issue here, since the try/except handler catches only API exceptions, not exceptions that the "stuff" parts could raise. I've added the decorator approach in the question statement. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

What about this ?

```
class ApiWrapper(object):

    def __init__(self, api):
        self._api = api

    def api_call(self, methodname, *args, **kwargs):
        method = getattr(self._api, methodname)
        try:
            return method(*args, **kwargs)
        except ApiException:
            print 'ApiWrapper caught an ApiException. Doing complicated error handling logic. Raising a different exception.'
            raise ApiWrapperException

    def do_one_thing(self):
        print 'do_one_thing stuff before API call'
        self.api_call("do_one_thing")
        print 'do_one_thing stuff after API call'
```